# What is the number of partitions of a set of size $16$ into $4$ subsets of size $4$?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, multinomial-coefficients

What is the number of partitions of a set of size $16$ into $4$ subsets of size  $4$ ?

*What I have done:*

I have tried ${16 \choose 4} \cdot \frac{{12 \choose 4}}{4!}$ however this gives an answer of $37537.5$ which has a decimal. Am I taking the right approach to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}}{{4!}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Also expressible using a multinomial coefficient: $$\frac{\binom{16}{4,4,4,4}}{4!}$$